# Haskell Yesod - CORS problems with browsers OPTIONS requests when doing POST requests

Tags: rest, haskell, request, cors, yesod

I have used `Network.Wai.Middleware.Cors`'s `simpleCors`, it worked properly for `GET` requests, but when I try to make a `POST` request I get the following problem

```
OPTIONS /users
  Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
  Status: 400 Bad Request 0.032443s
```

The only way I was able to make it work was by removing the `simpleCors` from the following part in `Application.hs`

```
-- | Convert our foundation to a WAI Application by calling @toWaiAppPlain@ and
-- applying some additional middlewares.
makeApplication :: App -> IO Application
makeApplication foundation = do
    logWare <- makeLogWare foundation
    -- Create the WAI application and apply middlewares
    appPlain <- toWaiAppPlain foundation
    return $ logWare $ defaultMiddlewaresNoLogging $ simpleCors $ appPlain
```

and adding a OPTIONS method response

```
optionsNewUserR :: Handler RepPlain
optionsNewUserR = do
  return $ RepPlain $ toContent ("" :: Text)
```

and adding CORS headers... But it is a dirty solution, because I would need to change ALL my API handlers! Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the issue is that [simpleCors](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-cors-0.2.5/docs/src/Network.Wai.Middleware.Cors.html#simpleCors) is built off [simpleCorsResourcePolicy](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-cors-0.2.5/docs/src/Network.Wai.Middleware.Cors.html#simpleCorsResourcePolicy), which only covers [simpleMethods](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-cors-0.2.5/docs/src/Network.Wai.Middleware.Cors.html#simpleMethods), which doesn't cover `OPTIONS`.

You can fix this issue by using the same methods to roll whatever middleware you need.

Here's the one I use for the `OPTIONS` problem you've described:

```haskell
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Middlewares where

import Network.Wai                       (Middleware)
import Network.Wai.Middleware.AddHeaders (addHeaders)
import Network.Wai.Middleware.Cors       (CorsResourcePolicy(..), cors)

-- | @x-csrf-token@ allowance.
-- The following header will be set: @Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-csrf-token@.
allowCsrf :: Middleware
allowCsrf = addHeaders [("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-csrf-token,authorization")]

-- | CORS middleware configured with 'appCorsResourcePolicy'.
corsified :: Middleware
corsified = cors (const $ Just appCorsResourcePolicy)

-- | Cors resource policy to be used with 'corsified' middleware.
--
-- This policy will set the following:
--
-- * RequestHeaders: @Content-Type@
-- * MethodsAllowed: @OPTIONS, GET, PUT, POST@
appCorsResourcePolicy :: CorsResourcePolicy
appCorsResourcePolicy = CorsResourcePolicy {
    corsOrigins        = Nothing
  , corsMethods        = ["OPTIONS", "GET", "PUT", "POST"]
  , corsRequestHeaders = ["Authorization", "Content-Type"]
  , corsExposedHeaders = Nothing
  , corsMaxAge         = Nothing
  , corsVaryOrigin     = False
  , corsRequireOrigin  = False
  , corsIgnoreFailures = False
}
```

And then just compose the middlewares you need like you're already doing:

```
run port $ logger . allowCsrf . corsified $ app cfg
```

Comment: Actually I was in the right path, I did the same you did, by comparing with the simpleCors implementation, but instead of `corsRequestHeaders = ["Authorization", "Content-Type"]` I used  `corsRequestHeaders = []`. What does this part do? Another thing, what IDE/Editor do you use to code in Haskell :) ?

Comment: Another thing, I had to add  `import Prelude`

Comment: Documentation is your friend! Check out https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-cors-0.2.5/docs/src/Network.Wai.Middleware.Cors.html#corsMethods

Your project must exclude the Prelude globally perhaps? I just use Sublime Text or Vim, but these are probably more general questions suited for off-question discussion!

Answer (score 3):

Simplifying the answer of Mario we can use simplePolicy

```
import Network.Wai.Middleware.Cors 

allowCors :: Middleware
allowCors = cors (const $ Just appCorsResourcePolicy)

appCorsResourcePolicy :: CorsResourcePolicy
appCorsResourcePolicy =
    simpleCorsResourcePolicy
        { corsMethods = ["OPTIONS", "GET", "PUT", "POST"]
        , corsRequestHeaders = ["Authorization", "Content-Type"]
        }
```

And to use it:

```
main = scotty 8080 $ do
    middleware allowCors
    matchAny  "/" $ text "Success"
```